# Silverstripe LeftJoin WHERE two values

Tags: mysql, sql, silverstripe

I have a many_many relationship between the Class Customer and the Class Product.
For example

DB Customer

```
| ID  | Name  |
-----------------------
| 01 | Jack   |
| 02 | Joe    |
| 03 | Claire |
```

DB Pruduct

```
| ID  | ProductName |
---------------------------------
| 01 | watch        |
| 02 | pen          |
| 03 | car          |
```

So after dev/build i get a new DB table called Customer_Products where the IDs of both Classes are.
Lets say the Customers have added some products like the folowing
DB Customer_Products

```
| ID  | CutomerID | PruductID |
----------------------------------------------------
| 01 |  01        |  01       |    -> Jack added watch
| 02 |  02        |  01       |    -> Joe added watch
| 03 |  01        |  02       |    -> Jack added pen
| 04 |  01        |  03       |    -> Jack added car
| 05 |  03        |  01       |    -> Claire added watch
```

Now i want to show only the customers that added **watch AND pen AND car** (for example). 
So I want to use a query to show only Jack because he added the 3 products. And here is my problem/question. 
My code:

```
$sqlQuery = new SQLQuery();
$sqlQuery->setFrom("Customer"); 
$sqlQuery->addLeftJoin(' Customer_Products ','"Customer"."ID" = " Customer_Products "."CustomerID"');
$sqlQuery->addWhere("PruductID = 01  ");

// with this next two lines the result is empty, I know this is wrong but maybe this gives you an idea of what I m looking for. 
// $sqlQuery->addWhere("PruductID = 02 ");                  
// $sqlQuery->addWhere("PruductID = 03  ");     

$rawSQL = $sqlQuery->sql();
$rec = $sqlQuery->execute();
```

Is there a way to do this with one query? Or how I could do this? Thanks for Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several approaches.  I like the `group by` and `having` approach, because it is the most flexible:

```
select c.*
from customers c join
     customer_products cp
     on c.customerid = cp.customerid join
     products p
     on p.productid = cp.productid
where p.name in ('Pen', 'Car', 'Watch')
group by c.customerid
having sum(p.name = 'Pen') > 0 and
       sum(p.name = 'Car') > 0 and
       sum(p.name = 'Watch') > 0;
```

Each condition in the `having` clause is testing for the presence of one product.  The `where` clause is optional but it can help performance.

Comment: is it possible to use more than 1 tablejoins this way? Or should i use WHERE instead of Group by and having?

Comment: @user3786012 . . . I don't understand your question.

Comment: i mean when i must check other table too. for example: there are also the tables Adress, Settings, and many more.
i want to query folowing: 
show me all customers who added the products 01 AND 02 AND 03 AND live in Ardess.City = 'London' AND have the Settings.xyz = 'x' AND so on.

Comment: @user3786012 . . . Of course.  The conditions can come from any of the tables.